# How to use future builder in title and body?

Tags: flutter

I have future builder working for the body of my app but not in the title. Please can you tell me how to use future builder in the title section, but still be able to access the same results array in the body section (without having to resend the database query in the body section)

This is the existing code with future builder working in the body section:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(data["name"]), // !!! need to be able to display data["name"] here

  ),
  body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    future: docRef.get(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(
          // child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
          child: Text("Oh no it's an error"),
        );
      } else {
        final data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(data?["name"] ?? '' + " is my name"),
            Text(data?["shoe_size"] ?? '' + " is my shoe size"),
```

Comment: can you move the futurebuilder to the caller of your scaffold class?

Comment: `future: docRef.get()`... Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to move the `Scaffold` one level up the tree. Meaning, wrap the entire page in a `FutureBuilder` and render a `Scaffold` once there's data/error.

Answer (score 0):

For me the simplest answer would be to just create a variable which can be null. When the future builder has loaded the data, just assign the data to the variable with setState() and then in the app bar just do:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(variableThatHoldsTheData ?? "Loading..."), 
  ),
  body:
```

Another way is to load the data in initState and while your variable is null, just show a loading indicator on the page and then update it